# aura:id is coming to be undefined for the first row in table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-id

first error is -> Action failed: c:xyz_Cmp$controller$onKeyUp [Cannot read property 'get' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {c:xyz$controller$onKeyUp}

second error is -> Action failed: c:xyz_Cmp$controller$onKeyUp [Cannot read property 'match' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {c:xyz_Cmp$controller$onKeyUp}

following is the code :

Sorry, new to stackexchange , following is the component markup

```
<tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.cont}" var="item" indexVar="ind">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="" scope="col">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate"> 
                                        <lightning:input type="text" variant="label-hidden" disabled="true" value="{!item.x__c}"  placeholder="" pattern="\d{5}-\d{3}-\d{2}" maxlength="12" messageWhenBadInput=Invalid" messageWhenPatternMismatch="Invalid"/>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="" scope="col">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate"> 
                                        <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="fieldId" variant="label-hidden" required="true" name="input2"  value="{!item.y__c}" pattern="^[1-9]\d{4}$" maxlength="5" messageWhenBadInput="Invalid" messageWhenPatternMismatch="Invalid" placeholder=""/>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="" scope="col">
                                    
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!item.z__c}">
                                        <ui:inputText aura:id="searchInput"
                                                      keyup="{!c.onKeyUp}" value= "{!item.z__c}" class="slds-input" 
                                                      updateOn="keyup" />
                                        <span id="{!'ValidationError'+ind}" style="color: red; display:none;">{!v.errormessage}</span>   
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
```

---

js controller :

``````````````````````````
onKeyUp: function(component, event, helper)
                                        {
                                            let PList = component.get("v.cont");
                                            
                                             for(var i=0;i<PList.length;i++)
                                             {
                                                 
                                                 var searchInput = component.find('searchInput');
                                                 
                                                 var nvalue = searchInput[i].get("v.value");
                                                
                                                var patt = /^(\d{5}-\d{3}-\d{2})$|^(\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{2})$|^(\d{5}-\d{4}-\d{1})$|^(\d{5}-\d{4}-\d{2})$/;
                                                
                                                 if(nvalue.match(patt))
                                                 {
                                                     component.set("v.errorcheck",false);
                                                     component.set("v.errormessage",'');
                                                     document.getElementById("ValidationError"+i).style.display = 'none'; 
                                                 }
                                                 else if(!ndcvalue.match(patt))
                                                 {
                                                     component.set("v.errorcheck",true);
component.set("v.errormessage",'Invalid, Please Enter Valid Format.');               document.getElementById("ValidationError"+i).style.display = 'block'; 

                                                 }                             
                                             }
                                        }
`````````````````````````

code is not working, not sure how to resolve it. searchInput is coming to be undefined
``````````````````````````

Comment: Please format the code using *{}* or Ctrl + K & add component code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see any specific use of using `aura:id's` here. Since `updateOn` on **ui:inputText attribute** itself does that.

You can use the keyup event & add whatever you're trying to do because you already have the updated value in the list.

```
    onKeyUp : function(c, e , h){
       let contactList = c.get('v.cont');
       var patt = /^(\d{5}-\d{3}-\d{2})$|^(\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{2})$|^(\d{5}-\d{4}-\d{1})$|^(\d{5}-\d{4}-\d{2})$/;
       contactList.forEach((contact) =>{
       if(contact.z__c !== undefined){
          if(contact.z__c.match(patt)){
             //put your validation code inside here
           }
        }
        else{
         //this was a newly added row .. add validation for it here
        }
       });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. I don't get the first error anymore. Although second error still gets thrown : Action failed: c:xyz_Cmp$controller$onKeyUp [Cannot read property 'match' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {c:xyz_Cmp$controller$onKeyUp}
it works fine till i select one record (row) for the table but as soon as another row is added , it throws the above mentioned error.

Comment: Does the row added have any value of z__c in it? If it was dynamically added you can simply ignore the case by adding an undefined check. Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks a ton!! that worked !! thank you